I am making a web app with Flask/ Python, trying to show QR-code in a table, but it is not showing,
I am learning Flask/ Python, i got a problem i cannot resolve myself, i have also tried chatgpt but it says everything is correct (but its not working)
I make a webapp where you can type in your name, and a qr-code will be generated and stored in the database (mysql/ xampp)
This is working, i encode to base64 and store it as a blob:
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def skjema():
msg = ''
qr_kode_data = None

if request.method == 'POST':
    forNavn = request.form['forNavn']
    etterNavn = request.form['etterNavn']
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    
    
    try:
        # Generer QR-koden baser på inputdata
        data = forNavn + ' ' + etterNavn 
        qr = qrcode.make(data, box_size=1)

        # Lagre QR-koden i en BytesIO buffer
        img_buffer = BytesIO()
        qr.save(img_buffer)
        img_buffer.seek(0)

        # Konverter QR-koden til base64
        qr_kode_data = base64.b64encode(img_buffer.getvalue()).decode('utf-8')

        # Sjekk om bruker allerede eksisterer i databasen
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM qrkode WHERE forNavn = %s AND etterNavn = %s", (forNavn, etterNavn,))
        eksisterer_bruker = cur.fetchone()

        if eksisterer_bruker:
            msg = "Bruker eksisterer fra før av"
        else:
            # Legg til ny bruker med qrKode i databasen
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO qrkode (forNavn, etterNavn, qrKode) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (forNavn, etterNavn, qr_kode_data,))
            mysql.connection.commit()
            msg = "Bruker lagt til i databasen"
            #print(qr_kode_data)
 
    finally:
        if img_buffer:
            img_buffer.close()
        cur.close()

# Hent alle brukerne fra databasen
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM qrkode")
alle_brukere = cur.fetchall()
print(alle_brukere)
cur.close()
    
return render_template('skjema.html', msg=msg, qr_kode_data=qr_kode_data, alle_brukere=alle_brukere)

And this is my show_qr route:
app.route('/qrkoder', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def vis_qrkoder(brukerID):
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT qrKode from qrkode WHERE brukerID = %s", 
(brukerID,))
alle_qrKoder = cur.fetchall()
cur.close()

return 
render_template('skjema.html',alle_qrKoder=alle_qrKoder)

The problem i am having is that my table in html are showing all the names, but the qr code is not showing, i have testet different code also bruker[3] ect but nothing is working.
table>
            <tr>
                <th>Fornavn</th>
                <th>Etternavn</th>
                <th>QR-kode</th>
            </tr>
            {% for bruker in alle_brukere %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ bruker[1] }}</td>
                <td>{{ bruker[2] }}</td>
                <td><img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ alle_qrkoder }}" alt="QR-kode"></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            
/table>

I got it to show one qr-code when i registered one user, but now when i want to show all of them, the same code does not work.
I think my main problem is this code.
<tr>
            <td>{{ bruker[1] }}</td>
            <td>{{ bruker[2] }}</td>
            <td><img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ alle_qrkoder }}" alt="QR-kode"></td>
        </tr>

because its the showing thats not working, but there also might be something wrong with this:
   app.route('/qrkoder', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
   def vis_qrkoder(brukerID):
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT qrKode from qrkode WHERE brukerID = %s", (brukerID,))
    alle_qrKoder = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()

    return render_template('skjema.html', alle_qrKoder=alle_qrKoder)







    


Why are you base64 encoding the image before storing it? That just bloats the image. It's not clear what the /qrkoder route has to do with this, as the template snippet is iterating over alle_brukere, not alle_qrKoder. As you have used SELECT * we have no idea what the columns are or what order they are in.

Thanks for the reply i figurd it out, no base64 encoding and just making qr.png in a folder, its working good now, i am sorry for non existing information from me but i just dont know what information people need on this forum to help.
